# Comparing multiple files by bytes

Tags: python, filesize, listdir

I want to compare multiple files of one directory with multiple files in another directory by their byte size in order to find the closest "match".
This is my code so far:

```
import os
# these are lists of all the filenames in respective directories
firstDir = os.listdir('first')
secondDir = os.listdir('second')
# I imagine using this for loop to compare the byte values, but I have no idea which method to use
for item in firstDir
    # ...
```

Comment: So you want us to complete your code? Sorry. Go to Python doc, search for file related function and do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started, the rest you should be able to figure out.

```
import os
p='yourdir'
firstDir = os.listdir(p)
for item in firstDir:
    print os.path.getsize(p+"/"+item)
```